# SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known | PHP Mailer 6.5

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

Trying to send mail using PHPMailer 6.5 (Current Latest Version). Most of the code is copy-pasted from the PHPMailer. So I hope so there is no need for an explanation.

**Error:**

```
2021-07-05 13:21:33 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: 

php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. (0)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Message has been sent
```

**Code**

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      //Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.example.com';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->Username   = 'foo@gmail.com';                     //SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = '*******';                               //SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
    $mail->Port       = 465;

    $mail->setFrom('foo@gmail.com', 'Megasoft Money');
    $mail->addAddress('foo2@gmail.com');
    $mail->addReplyTo('foo@gmail.com', 'Megasoft Money');

   
    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'PHP Mailer Subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'Hi, this is a test body.';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

Comment: It's exactly copy/pasted from the PHPMailer example, except for the part you left out, which is why it's breaking. Add the `use` statements back in. You don't need those `require` statements for individual classes if you're using composer. The readme covers how to load PHPMailer both with and without composer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to qualify the class name. Use either a `use` statement:

`use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;`

Or just fully qualify it:

`$a = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();`

I would recommend the `use` version because otherwise you’ll end up having to write the fully qualified version several times.

You’ll also have to repeat this with `SMTP`